# Consuming List and Outputing Same List That Aren't 0 - Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, structure, racket

For reference, I am programming with `Scheme` using `DrRacket`.

I am trying to consume the list `listofVotingTallies` and output `listofVotingTallies` but only output the candidates that have at least 1 vote. In this case, the only candidate that is supposed to be excluded from the list is "Joey".

When I run the program, I get the exact same list back. It appears my problem lies in the

`(cons (eliminate-no-votes (rest aloVT)))`

part of the definition of `eliminate-no-votes`.

```
;; Data Definition
(define-struct voting-tally (candidate numVotes))
;; A voting-tally is a structure: (make-voting-tally String Number). 
;; interp. a candidate (String) and how many votes said
;;         candidate has gotten (Number).

(define votesForBlake 
  (make-voting-tally "Blake" 5))

(define votesForAsh 
  (make-voting-tally "Ash" 7))

(define votesForBob 
  (make-voting-tally "Bob" 3))

(define votesForWill 
  (make-voting-tally "Will" 2))

(define votesForJoey 
  (make-voting-tally "Joey" 0))

(define listofVotingTallies
  (list votesForBlake votesForAsh votesForBob votesForWill votesForJoey))


;; Signature: eliminate-no-votes: list-of-Voting-Tallies -> list-of-Voting-Tallies
;; Purpose: Consumes a list of voting-tally and produces a list of those tallies
;;          in which the candidate received at least one vote.
;; Tests:
(check-expect (eliminate-no-votes empty) empty)
(check-expect (eliminate-no-votes listofVotingTallies) (list votesForBlake votesForAsh votesForBob votesForWill))
;; Define:
(define (eliminate-no-votes aloVT)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloVT) empty]
    [(> 0 (voting-tally-numVotes (first aloVT))) (cons (eliminate-no-votes (rest aloVT)))]
    [else (cons (first aloVT) (eliminate-no-votes (rest aloVT)))]
    )
  )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[(> 0 (voting-tally-numVotes (first aloVT))) (cons (eliminate-no-votes (rest aloVT)))]
```

is wrong, because

- `cons` needs 2 parameters
- it never gets executed because you actually test whether the number of votes is *negative* (0 > votes is the same as votes < 0)
- you try to skip an element here, and that should be the case when the count is 0

so you should do as follows:

```
(define (eliminate-no-votes aloVT)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloVT) empty]
    [(= 0 (voting-tally-numVotes (first aloVT))) (eliminate-no-votes (rest aloVT))]
    [else (cons (first aloVT) (eliminate-no-votes (rest aloVT)))]))
```